# Duplex forced selfstalemate

Tags: problems, records, stalemate

Ludwig Zagler, Chess Ultimates 12/1974

```
[FEN "3nBb2/3PRP2/2ppPPpp/2nk2pb/2p2QN1/1r1rBKP1/7q/8 w - - 0 0"]
```

self=1, 7 solutions

This is the record (7 variants) for forced single side selfstalemates. I expect that Zagler, who even made a systematic for one-mover records, also did the duplex version (*any* move for *both* sides selfstalemates), but could not dig it up on the existing databases.

Since one white and one black selfstalemate can be easily done with 8 pieces, please give at least 3 overall (or a link to an existing record).

Answer (score 1):

Whoever moves first is stalemated. There are four possible first moves for both sides, thus creating four variations.

```
[FEN "8/8/8/1p1p1p1p/8/1P1PpP1P/4Pp1p/5K1k w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Of course I meant a onemover (you can also push the black pawns one file further back) but not accounting for tricky problemists fully goes on the asker :-)